# How do you provide a specific error message with optparse-applicative when multiple mutually exclusive options are provided?

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments

It's easy to specify mutually exclusive options with [optparse-applicative](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative):

```
data Exclusive = E1 | E2

exclusiveParser :: Parser ExclusiveOption
exclusiveParser = 
        (flag' E1 (short 'e1')
    <|> (flag' E2 (short 'e2')
```

The above parser will parse either `-e1` or `-e2`, but not both. The default optparse-applicative action when both `-e1` and `-e2` are provided is to print the application's usage message. I would like to provide the user with a specific error message informing them that they cannot provide both `-e1` and `-e2`, but I don't see an obvious way to do that.

Any suggestions (or solutions) would be appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with optparse-applicative, so I'm not sure what error-printing facilities it provides. (Sometimes parser combinator libraries offer a primitive that changes the error that's printed, but I didn't see anything for that on a quick skim of the optparse-applicative docs. Entirely possible that I missed it.)

But in case nothing is available from the library itself, you could always print your own message by accepting both flags; e.g.

```
data Exclusive = E1 | E2 | Both
exclusiveParser
     =  (flag' E1 (short 'e'))
    <|> (flag' E2 (short 'f'))
    <|> (flag' Both (short 'e') <* flag' Both (short 'f'))
```

Then in your top-level handler (i.e. once the options are all parsed), if you see `Both`, you can issue an error message of your own crafting at that moment.

Comment: @ChristopherLewis Oh, sure; if you want, you could use `data Exclusive = E1 | E2` and return a `Maybe Exclusive` or `Except CommandLineParsingError Exclusive` or whatever, and that would probably be a cleaner design -- especially if it meant you could compose the parser and error-reporting applicatives.

Comment: [Deleted previous comment: hit enter too soon, but it's content is essentially included in this comment.] I'm marking this as the correct answer: after careful inspection I can find no better way to handle this situation. However, encoding the failure indicator in the sum type does leave a bad taste in my mouth. I should point out that optparse-applicative's error messages have been improved (added) since I originally posed this question. Since version 0.14 the parser in the question will output the error `Invalid option \`-e2'`.

Comment: I'm using the solution with version 1.2.1. Error **Invalid option `-e2'** is thrown BEFORE command line options are parsed. Thus I cannot check **Both**. How to get **Both**?